# Create boolean flag based on column value containing element of a List

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, dataset, conditional-statements

```
def myFunction(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    val myList= List("a","b","c")

    df
      .withColumn("myFlag",
        if (myList.contains(df.select(col("columnName1")))) lit("true") else lit(false))
}
```

I want to write a function, that takes a Dataframe, and adds a column to it, named "myFlag".

I want "myFlag" to be **true** if the corresponding "columnName1" has a value that is an element of "myList", **false** otherwise.

For simplicity, "columnName1" values and "myList" only contain Strings.

My function above will not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using `isin` which is defined on `Column`:

```
import spark.implicits._

df
  .withColumn("myFlag",$"columnName1".isin(myList:_*))
```

Comment: Not sure what the $ is doing. It doesn't seem to work so please explain or update.

Comment: the $ symbol is used when you want to refer to a column. so $"col1" will use the values of "col1" and do the subsequent operation, checking if it is in your List, in the example above. Alternatively you can write col("col1") which is the same thing to my knowledge